# How to implement conditional rendering in Stepper - Material UI? React.Js Step Progress Bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

Context: I need a card with the title: ''You have 16% complete profile!'', and a step progress bar with 6 steps (circles), which each has a condition behind it that must meet to be active. I have stuck here, because everything I find is with buttons, and I don't need one, I need to use conditional statements.

E.g:

- for circle 1 you must be authenticated;
- for circle 2 you must have a quiz done;
- for circle 3 you must have a profile picture;

I would like this step bar not to be a linear one, for example, if have a profile picture, but I didn't take the quiz, circle number 3 will be complete.

This Stepper will be connected to Redux.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { profile, user } = state.Login;
    const quiz = get( profile,'userData.quiz' );
    const profilePicture = get( profile,'userData.profilePictureId' );
    return {
      profile,
      isAuthenticated: !!user.accessToken,
      quiz,
      profilePicture 
    };
  };
  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    action
  };
```

The base of my code is taken from Material -Ui:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Stepper from '@material-ui/core/Stepper';
import Step from '@material-ui/core/Step';
import StepButton from '@material-ui/core/StepButton';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  button: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  backButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  completed: {
    display: 'inline-block',
  },
  instructions: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

function getSteps() {
  return ['Select campaign settings', 'Create an ad group', 'Create an ad'];
}

function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return 'Step 1: Select campaign settings...';
    case 1:
      return 'Step 2: What is an ad group anyways?';
    case 2:
      return 'Step 3: This is the bit I really care about!';
    default:
      return 'Unknown step';
  }
}

export default function HorizontalNonLinearAlternativeLabelStepper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = React.useState(new Set());
  const [skipped, setSkipped] = React.useState(new Set());
  const steps = getSteps();

  const totalSteps = () => {
    return getSteps().length;
  };

  const isStepOptional = (step) => {
    return step === 1;
  };

  const handleSkip = () => {
    if (!isStepOptional(activeStep)) {
      // You probably want to guard against something like this
      // it should never occur unless someone's actively trying to break something.
      throw new Error("You can't skip a step that isn't optional.");
    }

    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
    setSkipped((prevSkipped) => {
      const newSkipped = new Set(prevSkipped.values());
      newSkipped.add(activeStep);
      return newSkipped;
    });
  };

  const skippedSteps = () => {
    return skipped.size;
  };

  const completedSteps = () => {
    return completed.size;
  };

  const allStepsCompleted = () => {
    return completedSteps() === totalSteps() - skippedSteps();
  };

  const isLastStep = () => {
    return activeStep === totalSteps() - 1;
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    const newActiveStep =
      isLastStep() && !allStepsCompleted()
        ? // It's the last step, but not all steps have been completed
          // find the first step that has been completed
          steps.findIndex((step, i) => !completed.has(i))
        : activeStep + 1;

    setActiveStep(newActiveStep);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleStep = (step) => () => {
    setActiveStep(step);
  };

  const handleComplete = () => {
    const newCompleted = new Set(completed);
    newCompleted.add(activeStep);
    setCompleted(newCompleted);

    /**
     * Sigh... it would be much nicer to replace the following if conditional with
     * `if (!this.allStepsComplete())` however state is not set when we do this,
     * thus we have to resort to not being very DRY.
     */
    if (completed.size !== totalSteps() - skippedSteps()) {
      handleNext();
    }
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
    setCompleted(new Set());
    setSkipped(new Set());
  };

  const isStepSkipped = (step) => {
    return skipped.has(step);
  };

  function isStepComplete(step) {
    return completed.has(step);
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Stepper alternativeLabel nonLinear activeStep={activeStep}>
        {steps.map((label, index) => {
          const stepProps = {};
          const buttonProps = {};
          if (isStepOptional(index)) {
            buttonProps.optional = <Typography variant="caption">Optional</Typography>;
          }
          if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
            stepProps.completed = false;
          }
          return (
            <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
              <StepButton
                onClick={handleStep(index)}
                completed={isStepComplete(index)}
                {...buttonProps}
              >
                {label}
              </StepButton>
            </Step>
          );
        })}
      </Stepper>
      <div>
        {allStepsCompleted() ? (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>
              All steps completed - you&apos;re finished
            </Typography>
            <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Typography className={classes.instructions}>{getStepContent(activeStep)}</Typography>
            <div>
              <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack} className={classes.button}>
                Back
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={handleNext}
                className={classes.button}
              >
                Next
              </Button>
              {isStepOptional(activeStep) && !completed.has(activeStep) && (
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={handleSkip}
                  className={classes.button}
                >
                  Skip
                </Button>
              )}

              {activeStep !== steps.length &&
                (completed.has(activeStep) ? (
                  <Typography variant="caption" className={classes.completed}>
                    Step {activeStep + 1} already completed
                  </Typography>
                ) : (
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleComplete}>
                    {completedSteps() === totalSteps() - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Complete Step'}
                  </Button>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried a silly solution, but it doesn't work properly:

```
 function StepNavigation( isAuthenticated, quiz, profile, step, profilePicture ) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const steps = getSteps();
  
if (isAuthenticated) {
    step = 1
} else 
  { step = 0 
};
console.log(step);
  if (bodyShape) {
    step = 2 
  } else 
  { step = 0 
}; console.log(step);
...
 <Stepper alternativeLabel  activeStep={step} ...>
```

I need your help, and I'm sorry for my mistakes! :(